# Insert dependent records in two tables at once?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I was working on admin module of my project and had to insert values into 2 or more tables simultaneously as they are dependent on each other and are connected via primary key. So for example table1 is building which is connected to table2 (roofings) and table3 (exteriors) via building_number and a new building has to be added then I need to update roofings and exteriors accordingly.

Is there anyway in Oracle 10g to insert values into 2 or more tables using single sql statement? I tried using inner join but that doesn't work. What can be best solution in such situation.

Thanks

Comment: In reading your question, it sounds to me like `roofings` and `exteriors` both have a reference to `buildings` (through `building_number`), but not the other way around (ie - `buildings` doesn't have an `exterior_number`).  Is this the case (at which point a normal transaction should suffice), or do you indeed have crossing FKs (at which point I would attempt to refactor the model, most probably)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way you can pass 2 table references to `INSERT`. But you can define your FK constraints as `DEFERRABLE`, so they will be checked when you commit transaction, not when you insert data into the tables. Take a look on this [example](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-triggers.html#deferring%20constraint%20checking)

Comment: And all us MS SQL Server users weep for this "standard but unsupported feature" :( +1 for mentioning deferrable constraints, which is the crux of inserting into tables with [co]recursive referential constraints. (Also, should make sure to use one transaction, but that might be without saying... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it would be great if MS implements it one day .

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you'd have an intermediate table between building and roofings and building and exteriors if you want the reference to go both ways, or have one-to-many or many-to-many relationships (not sure if that applies in your case).

In your case, you'd create your new building, roofing, and exterior objects without references to each other.  Since they have no references, there are no FK constraints when you add your objects.  Then you'd add an entry to the buildingRoofing table that ties the building to the roofing, and an entry in the buildingExteriors table that ties the building to the exterior.  Last, you commit your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a multi table insert, using [INSERT ALL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2121682)

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine any performance benefits of doing inserting values into two tables with the same statement, but try [this](http://www.rndblog.com/insert-into-multiple-mysql-tables-linked-by-a-foreign-key/) link.

Comment: This "issue" is when two newly inserted records are part of [co]recursive referential integrity constraint. Without deferable (or disabled or missing) constraints the first insert will fail because it is dependent upon the second.